# Magento 2: target="_blank" in UI Listing Action Links

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, uicomponent

In Magento 2, you can create "Action" links for your UI grid.  Magento itself does this on the CMS Listing Grid here

```
#File: vendor/magento/module-cms/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/PageActions.php
//...
$item[$name]['edit'] = [
    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($this->editUrl, ['page_id' => $item['page_id']]),
    'label' => __('Edit')
];

//...
```

Is there a way to have these action links open in a new window? (the same way an `<a href="..." target="_blank">Link Test</a>` would work.  I've tried added both a `target` and `window` to the array that creates the link, but that doesn't appear to work.

If I look at the source of a rendered link

```
<a class="action-menu-item" data-bind="
        attr: {
            href: $action().href
        },
        click: $col.getActionHandler($action()),
        text: $action().label" data-repeat-index="0" href="http://google.com">View Log</a>
```

I see a bunch of modern abstract javascript who's ultimate source is difficult to track down.

The specific question I'd like answered is "how to make action links open in a new window using the provided UI abstractions" (I know I could add my own javascript to the page that handles it, but that seems like a hack solution for something that's so simple in plain old HTML)

A larger question that I'll accepts an answer for is

1. Where are the action links rendered
2. Where the javascript source for the `$col.getActionHandler...` code below

Comment: Hello Alan .. Can you please explain how can I add target="_blank" in UI component column showing in the grid. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In `Magento 2.1.*` target `_blank` is not working

Following file is responsible to render action in admin `UI component Grid`

```
vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/cells/actions.html
```

Change:

> ```
> attr="href: $action().href" 
>
> to 
>
> attr="target: $col.getTarget($action()), href: $action().href"
> ```

For action dropdown change:

> ```
>  attr="href: $action().href, 'data-action': 'item-' +
>  $action().index"
>
>  to
>
>  attr="target: $col.getTarget($action()), href: $action().href, 'data-action': 'item-' + $action().index"
> ```

Or replace below code in `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/cells/actions.html`:

```
<a
class="action-menu-item"
if="$col.isSingle($row()._rowIndex)"
repeat="foreach: $col.getVisibleActions($row()._rowIndex), item: '$action'"
click="$col.getActionHandler($action())"
text="$action().label"
attr="href: $action().href"/>

<div class="action-select-wrap" if="$col.isMultiple($row()._rowIndex)" collapsible>
    <button class="action-select" translate="'Select'" toggleCollapsible/>
    <ul class="action-menu" css="_active: $collapsible.opened">
        <li repeat="foreach: $col.getVisibleActions($row()._rowIndex), item: '$action'">
            <a class="action-menu-item" click="$col.getActionHandler($action())" text="$action().label" attr="href: $action().href, 'data-action': 'item-' + $action().index"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Replace with below code

```
<a
    class="action-menu-item"
    if="$col.isSingle($row()._rowIndex)"
    repeat="foreach: $col.getVisibleActions($row()._rowIndex), item: '$action'"
    click="$col.getActionHandler($action())"
    text="$action().label"
    attr="target: $col.getTarget($action()), href: $action().href"/>

<div class="action-select-wrap" if="$col.isMultiple($row()._rowIndex)" collapsible>
    <button class="action-select" translate="'Select'" toggleCollapsible/>
    <ul class="action-menu" css="_active: $collapsible.opened">
        <li repeat="foreach: $col.getVisibleActions($row()._rowIndex), item: '$action'">
            <a class="action-menu-item" click="$col.getActionHandler($action())" text="$action().label" attr="target: $col.getTarget($action()), href: $action().href, 'data-action': 'item-' + $action().index"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Add below function to `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/actions.js` which is already there in `Magento 2.2`

```
/**
 * Returns target of action if it's been set.
 *
 * @param {Object} action - Action object.
 * @returns {String}
 */
getTarget: function (action) {
    if (action.target) {
        return action.target;
    }

    return '_self';
},
```

Now Use : 
 #File: `Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/PageActions.php`

```
//...
$item[$name]['edit'] = [
    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($this->editUrl, ['page_id' => $item['page_id']]),
    'target' => '_blank',
    'label' => __('Edit')
];
```

Now, Target `_blank` will work for `Magento 2.1.*` versions

Answer (score 3):

alan UI in mag2 uses knockoutjs for rendering the actions inside the grid.
we have vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/actions.js file  responsible for this column with  datatype  action and its uses as template`(bodyTmpl: 'ui/grid/cells/actions',)`, inside UI module, you will find vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/cells/actions.html the template responsible for rendering :

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko if: $col.isSingle($row()._rowIndex) -->
<a
    class="action-menu-item"
    data-bind="
        repeat: {
            foreach: $col.getVisibleActions($row()._rowIndex),
            item: '$action'
        }"
    data-repeat-bind="
        attr: {
            href: $action().href
        },
        click: $col.getActionHandler($action()),
        text: $action().label"
    ></a>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: $col.isMultiple($row()._rowIndex) -->
<div
    class="action-select-wrap"
    data-bind="collapsible">
    <button class="action-select" data-bind="toggleCollapsible">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Select'"></span>
    </button>
    <ul
        class="action-menu"
        data-bind="
            css: {'_active': $collapsible.opened}">
        <li
            data-bind="
                repeat: {
                    foreach: $col.getVisibleActions($row()._rowIndex),
                    item: '$action'
                }">
            <a
                class="action-menu-item"
                data-bind="
                    attr: {
                        href: $action().href
                    },
                    click: $col.getActionHandler($action()),
                    text: $action().label"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

yes, it fills the data of  tag with js ... here 2 cases for more than action it gives you select, and for one action simple a tag.
as result, I can't see how we can add extensible target blank just by using a custom module -_-

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with adding `'target' => '_blank'` below:

```
 #File: Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/PageActions.php
    //...
    $item[$name]['edit'] = [
        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($this->editUrl, ['page_id' => $item['page_id']]),
        'target' => '_blank',
        'label' => __('Edit')
    ];

 //...
```

Comment: Do you happen to know what sort of javascript that renders?

Answer (score 0):

**Add 'target' => '_blank' tag. Please refer below.**

> Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/PageActions.php

```
$item[$name]['edit'] = [
    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($this->editUrl, ['page_id' => $item['page_id']]),
    'target' => '_blank',
    'label' => __('Edit')
];
```

Comment: This file doesn't exist in M2.3.0

Do you know where it would be in 2.3.x?

Comment: In fact, I don't see this file in ANY of the versions of M2...What version were you using?